# Como criar botão em um SimpleAdapter com o evento click excluindo o item

Tags: android

Montei uma lista em um aplicativo android que é uma simples lista usando `SimpleAdapter`.

O que preciso agora é excluir o item da lista, mas não sei como faria isso porque não consegui pegar a posição do botão clicado.

Segue o código:

```
public class MostrarTodasTarefas extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mostrartodastarefas);

        String[] de = { "url", "status", "lastexecute", "btnExcluir" };
        int[] para = { R.id.lblURL, R.id.lblStatus, R.id.lblLastExecute, R.id.btnExcluir};

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, convertToMap(),
                R.layout.layout_listaurls, de, para);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listTarefas);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
                  @Override
                  public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {

                      if (view.getId() == R.id.btnExcluir) {

                          Button b = (Button) view;
                          b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                              @Override
                              public void onClick(View v) {

                                  Excluir(v);
                              }
                          });

                          return true;
                      }

                      return false;
                  }
              }
        );
    }

    public void Excluir(View view){
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("Excluido"));
    }
}
```

Ele cria a `ListView` e os `Button`'s.

Onde eu chamo `Excluir(v)` funciona, ele executa esse click em todos os botões da lista.

O que não sei fazer é pegar a posição para fazer a exclusão, o que preciso fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar o elemento clicado e sua posição em uma **List View** você deve fazer com que sua **List View** implemente o método `onItemClickListener`. Suponha que você tenha uma List View onde cada item é um `Usuario`. Para pegar um determinado usuário, você faria o seguinte:

```
/*
    Declaração e inicialização da List View e dos Adapters.
*/

minhaListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> meuAdapter, View minhaView, int posicaoSelecionada, long lng) {

    Usuario usuarioSelecionado =(Usuario) (minhaListView.getItemAtPosition(posicaoSelecionada));

    /*
         Realiza operações com o usuário obtido
    */
  }                 
});
```

**OBS.:** Modifique o nome do método `Excluir()` para `excluir()`, pois por convenção, métodos em Java devem ser escritos em camelCase, de maneira que a primeira palavra seja com letras minúsculas e cada palavra seguinte tenha a primeira letra maiúscula. Além disso, os métodos devem expressr ações e não devem possuir acentuação.  **Ex.:** `excluirUsuario()`, `calcularFrete()`

Comment: Desculpa a demora na resposta, onde vc vinculou que esse click seria o do botão? Não entendi onde o click do item acontece somente no click do botão que está dentro do item.

Comment: Desculpe, o código que eu postei é a solução para pegar a posição do item clicado, ou seja, se você clicar no botão, ele não pegaria a posição. Uma solução para o seu problema seria implementar um Custom Adapter, pois nele você poderia pegar a posição do item quando o botão for clicado e excluí-lo.

Comment: Tem algum link q mostre um código desses?

Comment: Tem este link [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076985/listview-row-buttons-how-do-i-create-a-custom-adapter-that-connects-a-view-oncl) . Apesar de estar em inglês ele está bem completo, portanto acho que vai te ajudar bastante.